# Passing a base64 string encoded image/ byte image as an image for processsing in Firebase ML Vision in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, mlvision

I want to OCR text from a base64 encoded image.
I know the image works because I can display it using

`Image.memory(base64Decode(captchaEncodedImgFetched))`

Now, the problem is I need to pass this image to Firebase ML Vision for processing.

The library `firebase_ml_vision` has an example for using a image from file

```
final File imageFile = getImageFile();
final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imageFile);`
```

However I have a base64 encoded image.

I tried the following

```
final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBytes(
base64Decode(captchaEncodedImgFetched));
```

But it seems to need  `FirebaseVisionImageMetadata()` as a argument, but I know nothing about byte images.

This class needs a lot more arguments which I don't understand.
For example, it needs a `size : Size(width, height)` argument. Isn't the image supposed to have a size already? Why do I need to specify it again?

For now I set it to `Size(200, 50)`. Then there are the other arugments and I don't know what to pass to them. For exmaple the `planeData` and `rawFormat`.

Here are the docs for these:

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_ml_vision/latest/firebase_ml_vision/FirebaseVisionImageMetadata-class.html

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_ml_vision/latest/firebase_ml_vision/FirebaseVisionImagePlaneMetadata-class.html

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_ml_vision/latest/

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseVisionImage.fromBytes` needs `FirebaseVisionImageMetadata` which intern needs `FirebaseVisionImagePlaneMetadata`. Example below :

```
// Below example uses metadata values based on an RGBA-encoded 1080x1080 image
final planeMetadata = FirebaseVisionImagePlaneMetadata(
    width: 1080,
    height: 1080,
    bytesPerRow: 1080 * 4,
);

final imageMetadata = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata(
    size: Size(1080, 1080),
    planeData: planeMetadata,
    rawFormat: 'RGBA', 
);

final visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBytes(decoded, metadata);
```

The simpler workaround though at a cost of performance is to write the bytes to the disk and read the image from there, as :

```
File imgFile = File('myimage.png');
imageFile.writeAsBytesSync(decoded.ToList());

final visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imageFile);
```

Comment: Can you explain what `planeMetadata`` is?

Comment: Also why do we need to define size, isn't it already available in the base64 data? Is there any way to extract the details using a function and pass them instead of specifying manually or is the data non existent?